# Login Loop on fresh install

Tags: greeter

I'm a novice Elementary OS user - to the point where this is my first installation...ever.

I had a spare Windows 10 Acer laptop and decided to do a fresh install of Elementary OS on it, so this is a clean installation where the username and password was created during installation. I have now tried reinstalling the OS multiple times and seem to be stuck in the same loop.

What happens is when the install is completed and the laptop restarts, Im greeted with a login screen. When I enter the password, the screen goes black for a second, and I'm back to the login screen.

Can't seem to do anything - stuck in a loop.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: If you can login into tty with Ctr+Alt+F1 (you can use any key from F1-F6) type `systemctl status lightdm`. Please edit your question with the output of the command.

Comment: also share the output of `lspci | grep VGA`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can get additional information about various failures if you press [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [F1] (F1 - F6). This takes you to a new "tty" or terminal. You may be asked to log in, so type in your username and password here. If you get to log in successfully then you can run `dmesg` to print out a bunch of debug info and see if maybe a driver crashed.